# How to hide and show outlook calendars on another computer

Tags: properties, calendar, outlook-addin

On my computer with office 2016 64bit I am able to use http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B to hide an outlook calendar. But when the app runs from my test computer (office 2013 23 bit) the code just breaks and it stops execution without raising an error

Maybe the proptags are office version dependent? Do you know how to handle this problem?

the actual code is:
`

```
                outlookApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
                primaryCalendar = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
                (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
                Outlook.MAPIFolder setcalendar = primaryCalendar.Folders["mycal"];
                Outlook.PropertyAccessor propertyaccesor = (Outlook.PropertyAccessor)setcalendar.PropertyAccessor;
                string stringprop = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B";
                bool bHidden = propertyaccesor.GetProperty(stringprop);
                propertyaccesor.SetProperty(stringprop, false);`
```

Comment: Please show your actual code. Are you saying Outlook just exits when you set that property?

Comment: I have to add that getproperty works but setproperty fails.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: after testing, I found that it works !sometimes! meaning under some configuration it worked for users while in another configuration it did not work for administrators! The thing is that there is nothing wrong with the code. Still if anyone knows of the rules\configuration\privileges that is needed to run I would gladly read about'em. That is me and all seekers of outlook automation.